# Is it possible to draw in Java with Graphics without paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I wanted to access the Graphics class to draw a rectangle, but wanted to do so without having to call the paintComponent method. Is it possible?

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. For example, *why* are you wanting to avoid using paintComponent? What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: For example, yes, it's possible to get a component's Graphics context object by calling `getGraphics()` and drawing with that, but in doing so, you risk creating unstable images and throwing NullPointerExceptions since a Graphics object obtained in this way is not durable.

Comment: besides, one does not call the paintComponent() method, right?

Answer (score 3):

Painting should always be done in a painting method.

The most common way is to do the custom painting in the `paintComponent(...)` method of the component.

Another approach is to "decorate" a component using the `JLayer` class and implement the painting in the `paint(...)` method of the JLayer. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Decorating Components Using the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, the same way it is possible to paint in a `BufferedImage` (by using straight the `Graphics` object by calling into the `getGraphics()` method).

**BUT**, unlike the case for `BufferedImage`, doing so for a component is likely to cause a mess. The reason is the underlying AWT/Swing code expects the component to paint itself, (see `Component.paint` or `JComponent.paintComponent`) while it (the underlying AWT/Swing code) will take care by about *when this rendering needs to occur* (e.g. scrolling, resizing, etc).

As such, if you paint from outside the component, at any time the AWT/Swing decides "Well, there's some new painting/repainting to be done", it will invoke the "standard methods", with the expectation your drawing code is there.
 As you paint it externally, *if you don't make special arrangements to be notified of the "need repainting" situation*, parts or the entire "drawing-from-outside" will be painted over or not painted at all or all kind of different messy situation.

In other words, if you paint-from-outside, you'll need to write not only the code that does the painting, but also:

1. re-implement heaps of code already implemented by the AWT/Swing which deals with the circumstances when the component needs to be (re)painted.
2. disable somehow the AWT/Swing "native" handling of painting.

Rest assured, **you don't want that** (even if you think you do).

PS. if you describe better why do you need that, you may get more useful suggestions on how to do it the proper way.